# Does the twin paradox ensure the quantum unitarity near a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, quantum-gravity, time-dilation, unitarity

A quantum system of two entangled particles is located near a black hole, particle A is receding from and particle B is moving towards the event horizon.

[image]

When particle B is crossing the event horizon, the quantum system seems to suffer a problem of unitarity.

But the 3 following thought experiments seem to show that there is no unitarity issue for particle A:

Case 1: Shortly after the division, particle B is changing its direction and approaching again particle A. In this case, due to gravitational time dilation, particle A is a little bit younger than particle B at the moment of their encounter.

Case 2: After the division, billions of years have passed for particle A. At this moment, from the point of view of the reference frame of particle A, particle B seems to be extremely near to the event horizon. If particle B managed to escape from the event horizon and to meet particle A again, particle A would be billions of years older than particle B.

Case 3: Now we come back to the initial description, particle A is receding and particle B is going through the event horizon. The unitary evolution is persisting until the moment when B is touching the event horizon. That is an infinite amount of time for particle A and a finite time lapse for particle B, as we saw in case 1 and case 2. Once B has crossed the event horizon, from the point of view of particle B the age of particle A can no longer be defined because particle A had reached already an age near the infinity limit, and also the unitary relation between A and B has approached an infinity limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a wrong assumption: In case 3 there is no infinite time dilation between A and B. The Schwarzschild coordinates have a singularity at the Schwarzschild horizon. Other coordinate choices as the kruskal-szekeres reveal that this singularity is no real singularity but due to your coordinate choice.

Also see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82678/does-someone-falling-into-a-black-hole-see-the-end-of-the-universe)

Comment: Your answer is not really answering my question, but you put me on the right way, thank you. I reformulated my question [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/311929/how-can-information-ever-get-lost-at-the-event-horizon-of-a-black-hole).