# $2$nd law of thermodynamics of an isolated system as it passes into a black hole?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, action

So I'm quite confused by this.

Let's say I have $2$ friends $A$ and $B$ with metrics:

$$ ds_A^2 = -dx_1^2 + dx_2^2$$

and

$$ ds_B^2 = dx_2^2 - dx_1^2$$

Ideally I would imagine a symmetry in their dynamics say:

$$ S_A(x_1,x_2) = S_B(x_2,x_1)$$

where $S$ is the action.

Let's say I have an isolated system in a box. Consider the second law of thermodynamics for an isolated system:

$$ \Delta S_{system}(t) \geq 0$$

Now, if I throw the box in a blackhole. Now, considering [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/354457/150174):

> The point of all this is that the coordinates are not spacetime - they
> are just labels we attach to spacetime. What happens inside an event
> horizon is not that time and space swap places but rather that the
> labels we call Schwarzschild coordinates behave oddly inside a black
> hole.

Is the following true for the box after passing the horizon?

$$ \Delta S_{system}(t) \geq 0$$

Or is it?

$$ \Delta S_{system}(r) \geq 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second one.

From equivalence principle and relativity principle, the (small) box physics is governed by its proper time and proper time under event horizon grows as $r$ shrinks.