# Who wins the race between an astronaut falling towards a black hole and the event horizon shrinking due to Hawking radiation?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, observers, hawking-radiation

From an external point of view, an astronaut falling towards a black hole takes an infinite amount of time to reach the horizon, while the horizon vanishes in finite time due to Hawking radiation. Does the infalling astronaut agree about the black hole evaporating before she reaches it?

Comment: Before I answer "yes", I want to make sure I understand you. Do you have a reason to think she would not agree?

Comment: The infalling observer will become part of the Hawking radiation, google "stretched horizon."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shouldn't it be impossible to fall into a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/581660/shouldnt-it-be-impossible-to-fall-into-a-black-hole)

Comment: "Stretched horizon" was the keyword I needed to google. Thanks!