# Does someone falling into a black hole see the future falling objects?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, event-horizon, observers

For someone falling into a black hole space and time swaps signs - the time coordinate of an outside observer becomes his space coordinate. That means, for any plane parallel to the horizon and inside the horizon, everything that happens, happened or will ever happen becomes simultaneous to a falling observer. It means he can see the bodies fallen after him (with respect to the outside observer) , once he crosses the horizon - because they lie in his past light from them can reach him.

Am I right?

Edit: I did not ask anything about seeing the end of the universe, or even any future event outside the horizon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does someone falling into a black hole see the end of the universe?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82678/does-someone-falling-into-a-black-hole-see-the-end-of-the-universe)

Comment: Nope. Totally irrelevant.

Comment: You don't directly see distant events; what you see is light that enters your eye. If your eye is inside a black hole , then the light you see is also inside: it's another object that fell in. "Does someone falling into a black hole see the end of the universe?" could also be phrased "Does someone falling into a black hole see light that falls in from arbitrarily late times in the universe's history?" If it's not a duplicate, it's at least highly relevant.

Comment: I did not ask if he sees lights from objects arbitrarily late in the future. Please read the question again.