# Would a black hole's event horizon split up a hadron into it's constituant quarks? Therefore creating free quarks?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, strong-force

As a thought experiment, say, for the sake of simplicity, we have a meson. This meson, which is traveling near light speed, is traveling towards a black hole. And skirts the event horizon in such a way where the anti-quark ends up inside it's event horizon, but the quark does not. What would happen? Would this create a free quark? That seems like the only logical thing to happen, but I know that would also break color confinement.

Comment: why should the other quark escape, both will fall in.

Comment: @Yukterez, the meson approaches the black hole in such a way where the anti-quark falls into the event horizon, while the quark just barely grazes the event horizon without falling it. The quark has enough velocity to escape the black hole.

Comment: it can't have enough velocity to escape if it grazes the black hole below the photon sphere at r=1.5rs, let alone close to the horizon at r≈1.0rs.

Comment: @Yukterez, The meson is not orbiting the black hole. It is on a hyperbolic trajectory. The photon sphere is the radius where a stable orbit can occur to my knowledge. The meson is not orbiting the black hole.

Comment: It is the radius at which the transversal velocity needs to be the higher than speed of light in order to escape, just like the horizon is the radius where the outward radial velocity needs to be higher than the speed of light. If you graze the black hole your closest approach to it is in transversal motion. If one quark is slightly below and the other slightly above they will stay together since the tidal forces are relatively small at the photon sphere (and mostly even at the horizon, extreme spaghettification only happens close to the singularity where both can't escape anyway).

Comment: @Yukterez, If nothing can escape the photon sphere, then why isn't that the event horizon?

Comment: You obviously didn't read carefully, search my comment for the keywords *radial* and *transversal*

Comment: Your question is based on a common lack of understanding of the geometry of a curved spacetime. One quark in a meson cannot cross the horizon without the other quark. See this comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/769334#comment1727087_769334

Comment: I have some Schwarzschild BH photon trajectory plots [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/680961/123208), and a link to a program you can use to generate your own plots. As you can see, if a photon crosses the photon sphere it is doomed, so a hadron has no hope, no matter how fast it's going.

Comment: I think the most plausible answer might bear on the nature of the BH's formation:  Nikodem Poplawski's local universes are formed by the gravitational collapse of rotating stars after their expenditure of their nuclear fuel, and their formations rely on a separation of particles from antiparticles during a hectic side effect that may differ from that of GR, as he uses Einstein-Cartan Theory (which gives fermions a tiny spatial extent):  This possibility seems unusually plausible because the question lacks a GR tag.  (Also,, PSE lacks an ECT tag, & I lack the rep 2 add 1.)

Comment: Anyone interested can go for it.

Comment: I'm not a particle physicist, but isn't this a cartoon picture of a meson? Two tiny spheres joined by a strong force string (flux tube). Likely from Feynman diagrams. Wouldn't the individual wavefunctions overlap and not be so assymetric, if not isotropic? 

Only when we probe with high energy particles do quarks look like they are composed of three separate objects, right?

Comment: @PM 2Ring. This doesn't solve the problem. Say the black hole is a quantum scale black hole. The anti-quark reaches the singularity but the quark does not have enough time to do so before the black hole totally decays. And the decay of the black hole does not emit any quarks or gluons(this is probabilistic to my knowledge), only leptons and bosons. What happens then?

Comment: @Colonizor48 If you rip a meson apart, you don't get free quarks. It hadronizes, forming a [jet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_(particle_physics)). A proton-sized (0.84 fm) BH has a lifetime of ~267 billion years, according to the [Hawking radiation calculator](https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator), and it's not easy to fire a meson at a tiny BH like that with a luminosity of ~1.1 GW. Also, we really need a theory of quantum gravity to analyse this scenario properly.

Comment: @PM 2Ring, assuming particles are point-like, the black hole can be arbitrarily small and the scenario is still possible. And due to the event horizon, the Quark and anti-quark cannot interact in any way. And it cannot just pull another anti-quark out of the vacuum without creating another quark. If it could, well we just found a solution to matter-antimatter asymmetry.

Answer (score 1):

I think they will stay togheter and both fall. Admitting that they crack apart, which i still doubt, the flux tube between them will gaun energy due to their spreading so when it snaps you get a full hadron inside and a full one outside

Comment: Wouldn't that be extracting work from a gravitational field?

Comment: Oh no, the black hole does work on the hadron which extract his energy out of the gluon field

Comment: The binding tube gain such a energy that i create a new pair of quarks

Comment: It wouldn't extract work out of the gravitational field any more than a body breaking apart due to tidal forces would.

Comment: This answer is incorrect and is based on a misunderstanding of the geometry of a curved spacetime. See my comment above under the question.

Comment: The link in your comment do not apply here. The light cone enters the horizon all together, but a hadron is made of 2 separate objects, so each quark has its own lightcone and the 2 cones do not enter together the horizon