Crossing an event horizon… at the end of time
I am not sure if my representation of entering into a black hole is correct, and so I would like to ask if I got anything wrong.
The black hole is getting closer. I know exactly when I will cross the event horizon, but I won't see anything special there, therefore I have created on my computer a simple animation that shows my spaceship on screen approaching an actual physical barrier (the event horizon), synchronized with real-time events.
At any point outside that barrier I know that I can theoretically turn back. But I also know that the more I approach that barrier the more my time will slow down for people far away, and so, if I do decide to go back, it might be in a very distant moment in the universe's future. Pick one year! 10000 CE? There is an exact point outside the event horizon in which if I switch on my engines and turn back, here on earth it will be the year 10000 CE. You prefer the year $1\,000\,000$ CE? There is also a point, further down in the black hole, still outside the event horizon, just for that. The year $10^{10^{10^{10}}}$? There is also a point for that.
What will the people on earth see me doing? Well, they won't see me, but they will know that I am suspended outside the event horizon, almost completely frozen in time. Eventually, if I do decide to come back in the year $10^{10^{10^{10}}}$, whoever will be alive in that moment will see me slowly leaving the black hole's surroundings and gaining life again.
But what if I do decide not to turn back and finally cross that event horizon?
Well, from the point of view of the universe, that event will happen at the end of time ($\infty$), because every instant i spend outside the event horizon already maps one instant of the universe's life outside the black hole.
As this applies to everything that falls into the black hole, for the universe nothing ever fell into it, not even the neutron star that formed the black hole in the first place: from the universe's perspective, every single atom of that neutron star is still hanging outside the horizon, and can, theoretically, decide to leave the black hole once and for all.
Very sad things do happen to me once I cross that boundary though: not only will I die, but as soon as I cross the horizon, my beloved universe will have already spent all its life. And so, my last moments after crossing the event horizon, before hitting the singularity, will be accompanied by the knowledge that I am at the end of time.
In a sense though, I will be the last one to die.
EDIT: Probably my question is not clear. What I am asking is: Is my picture correct?

I can't tell what your question is, please edit. Please distinguish from the potential duplicates about matter/bodies falling into black holes.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82678/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21319/123208

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

According to the current understanding, all black holes evaporate and will cease to exist in finite time. As such, you will not reach the event horizon before the complete black hole disappearance due to the evaporation.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
